# Not able to create a button in main activity from a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I would like to create a button in `MainActivity.java` for example, that is in a different fragment.

To be a bit more clear, I have an Activity that holds 3 fragments, I want to create a button from fragment 2 in that Activity. But when trying to initialize them, I get a null pointer exception.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.scoreFragment, new ScoreFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.questionFragment, new QuestionFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.navigationFragment, new NavigationFragment());

        //creates the questions
        questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        currentQuestion = new Question("correct");
        questions.add(currentQuestion);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

//here is where the null pointer exception appears.
        QuestionFragment q = (QuestionFragment)    fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.questionFragment);
        //View v = q.;
        initialize(q);
    }
    //Button nextQuestionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    //nextQuestionButton.setEnabled(false);

}


/* WHY DOESNT IT WORK? */
private void initialize(QuestionFragment q){

    View v=q.getView();

    buttons[0] = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttons[1] = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    buttons[2] = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    buttons[3] = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button4);


    //loads possible answers from array
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] answers = res.getStringArray(R.array.questionBank);


    //creates a random number between 0 and 3 that button is correct and the others are incorrect
    Random rand = new Random();
    int correct = rand.nextInt(4); 


    buttons[correct].setText(answers[0]);
    buttons[(correct + 1) % 4].setText(answers[1]);
    buttons[(correct + 2) % 4].setText(answers[2]);
    buttons[(correct + 3) % 4].setText(answers[3]); 
    }
```

I got it to work if I create the buttons in the `QuestionFragment` in `onCreateView` but I would like to try to make it work in `QuizActivity`, which holds the 3 fragments.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the activity. Fragments should handle their own functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overriding onCreateView in the QuestionFragment class, and do your QuestionFragment UI initialization there rather than trying to manage it from the Activity level.

Also, in your example above, if fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.questionFragment) is returning null then that means that the fragment hasn't been added/doesn't exist.

Comment: i actually initialized the ui in Question fragment class and it worked but im not sure if this is the correct way to do it. also, i want to know the reason why it doesn't work on MainActivity.

Comment: It's the correct way to do it.  In general think of an Fragment as a sub-activity: all logic that can be contained or encapsulated within the Fragment should go there vs. the Activity.  If you don't follow this pattern then all your logic will be bound to that Activity and you won't be able to easily re-use the fragment in a different Activity (which sort of defeats the whole purpose of Fragments).